# Is there a shortcut for Sublime Text to find an open file (Eclipse Ctrl + E)?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> of Sublime Text lets me find a file from all project files.

However, there are too many duplicated names. I’m looking for a shortcut key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in Eclipse, so that I just need to find the file in my opened file. That would save a lot of key striking.  Probably called “sidebar filter”?

Does not matter if it’s 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds easy to implement just select `Tools >> Developer >> New Plugin...` and add the content:

```py
import sublime_plugin
import os


def _show_name(name):
    return ([os.path.basename(name), name] if name
            else ["untitled", "untitled"])


class ShowBuffersCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        views = list(window.views())
        show_entries = [_show_name(v.file_name()) for v in views]

        def on_done(index):
            if index == -1:
                return
            window.focus_view(views[index])

        window.show_quick_panel(show_entries, on_done)
```

Afterwards save it into your `Package/User` folder and add this (or an other keybinding) to your keymap:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+e"],
    "command": "show_buffers"
},
```

(Tested on ST3)

Answer (score 2):

There is in Sublime Text a useful function called `Goto Anything`. You can access this by pressing `Ctrl + P` in Windows, and then you can search through any file located in a current project (to open a project, enable the sidebar, and drag and drop a folder from the explorer to the sidebar).

Comment: On macOS it's `⌘ + P`

Answer (score 1):

- Option One, Go to the "View" menu and choose "Side Bar", then "Show Open Files"
- Option Two, There is a small plugin here https://github.com/rrg/ListOpenFiles

Comment: Both of them only let me to see opened files....  but how can I navigate?

Comment: @Bomin Just click on the file you wish to navigate to

Comment: yeah... I'm trying to find a way to use the keyboard not mouse, for example, if there are 1aa.txt, b22.txt.  I can type "b", and it goes to b22.txt.

Comment: @Bomin Then try GoTo Anything [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html)

Comment: Thanks!  @r-stein gave me a perfect plugin.